# Where to find a database of AIS vessel information?

Tags: ais

The US Coast Guard provides a service by which a snippet of boat/ship identifying data, most typically an MMSI number, can be [used to retrieve a more complete data set](https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/aisSearch/dbo_aisVessels_list.php) of ship information, such as draft, name, dimensions, etc...

I'd like to download this database for offline usage. Is there, either (semi-)official or community created?